# 数値の時刻を分の時刻へ変換するやりかた

Tags: python, pandas

以下のように「年」「月」「日」「時間」のデータフレームがあり時間は数値で示されている場合、日時のインデックスを (2018−2−1 0:00) のような形で表す方法はありますでしょうか？

```
YEAR    MONTH   DAY HR
2018    2   1   0.0
2018    2   1   0.5
2018    2   1   1.0
2018    2   1   1.5
2018    2   1   2.0
```

時間は `0.5 = 30分` で1日48コマで表されています。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

データフレームが次のようなものであれば、

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2018, 2, 1, 0.0],
               [2018, 2, 1, 0.5],
               [2018, 2, 1, 1.0],
               [2018, 2, 1, 1.5]],
               columns=['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HR'])
```

Pandas の to_datetime()で datetime型に変換できます。ただし、列名が'HR'だとエラーになるので、'HOUR'に変更してから変換するようにします。時間の小数値は問題がないようです。

```
pd.to_datetime(df.rename(columns={'HR': 'HOUR'}))
```

これをインデックスにしたいのであれば、他にも列がある場合でも次のように書けます。

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HR']].rename(columns={'HR': 'HOUR'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
# Year, Month, Day, Hour, 
dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 1)
```

datatime型ではだめですか?
floatで指定できないので、適当に 整数にする必要はありますが。